# Omitting the date from auto insert template and modifying the items to sentence case

Tags: templates, datetime

I am using a template which insert the date automatically.
How I can remove the date? Besides, in itemizing it in upper case and put the text in center. I would like to have items in a sentence case and left.

the template:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height

\title{ 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge Spatial Planning in the Netherlands \\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Print the title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PROBLEM 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{What are the criteria that Needham (2007) uses to assess Dutch Planning?}
According to the article, there are two types of criteria for evaluation of Dutch spatial planning:


\subsection{Focusing on overall results and effects of planning. This category is consisted of three fundamental measures:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Accomplishment of goals and objectives of  spatial planning, 
\item To which extent cost is utilized, 
\item To what extent benefits and advantages of planning process are spread.  
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Itemize part:

[image]

Comment: use `\date{}` in the line before `\begin{document}`

Comment: For your second part, that you just added, i don't understand the question, could you provide an MWE?

Comment: @Ronny, the question is updated. I would like to have 0.1.1 in sentence case and align to left.

Comment: @user1885733 The second part of your question is still rather unclear. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Jubobs Currently it is in this style: FOCUSING ON OVERALL RESULTS AND EFFECTS OF PLANNING.
THIS CATEGORY IS CONSISTED OF THREE FUNDAMENTAL
MEASURES:  I would like to change it to: "Focusing on overall results and effects of planning. This category is consisted of three fundamental measures:"

Comment: Oh, with “sentence case” you mean “not in small caps“. @Jubobs already provided the answer, which solves the styling. If you further remove `\centering` the sections are aligned left.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To print no date: write `\date{}` in the preamble.
2. To use the normal font and left alignment for section headings: change line

`\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}`

to

`\allsectionsfont{\normalfont}`

In the future, **please post only one question per "TeX.SE question"**. Asking about two unrelated subjects (i.e., date and heading formatting) in the same "TeX.SE question" is considered bad practice.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, I think, the OP also wants the `section` title aligned left. Therefore, he should also remove the `\centering` in the code line you mentioned.

Comment: And +1 for mentioning bad practice :)

Comment: @Ronny Thanks. I fixed the alignment problem too :)